# Python BDD logic in step definition issue

Tags: python, bdd, scenarios

I have a scenario file that describes logging into an account;

```
Scenario: Failed login with blank login details
    Given I go to "BBC Login Page"
    When I fill in the username textfield with ""
    And I fill in the password textfield with ""
    And I press "Log in"
    Then I should see "In order to login, you must enter a valid user name."
```

In my step definitions (Python using Lettuce), which would fail unless I pass in the URL in my scenario (bad BDD);

```
@step('I go to "(.*?)"$')
def go_to(step, url):
    with AssertContextManager(step):
            world.browser.get(url)
```

Instead I want to build in a little bit of logic that substitutes the path for the real URL;

```
msr_login_page = "https://www.bbc.co.uk/login"

@step('I go to "(.*?)"$')
def go_to(step, url):
if url == "BBC Login page":
    urladjusted = msr_login_page
    with AssertContextManager(step):
            world.browser.get(urladjusted)
```

This fails with an error, and I don't appear to be able to set the URL variable at all no matter how I try to set it.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: "This fails with an error" - What error?

Comment: The error in pycharm is Message: f.QueryInterface is not a function

Comment: Is the indentation in your step definition just a typo made when copying it into Stack Overflow? The if statement should be indented.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a dictionary mapping for your page URLs by name?

```
urls = {"BBC Login page": "https://www.bbc.co.uk/login"}

@step('I go to "(.*?)"$')
def go_to(step, page):
    with AssertContextManager(step):
        world.browser.get(urls[page])
```

Comment: The dictionary would work, but how to I get the value of the incoming URL as specified in the scenario? Its the if statement thats not working.